# how to reinitialize the class instance decoded from jsonpickle

Tags: python, jsonpickle

Lets say I have this class

```
class LineItem:
   def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
```

When I encode this json with JSON pickle it will save all the attributes and class definition. And after encoding, lets say I change the class to following.

```
class LineItem:
   def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2
```

Now after changing the line item, if I decode the existing json with JSON pickle. The newly decoded class instance of LineItem will not have attribute var2. So if I try to access it, it will throw an error.

In my opinion, there should be an option to reinitialize the class instance.

Comment: Just call `__init__` explicitly? `obj.__init_()`.

Comment: You could give the class a `__setstate__()` method that knows to fill in the missing attribute if it's not present in the unpickled state.

Comment: I appreciate the valuable comments. IMO the solution you guys suggested is an external solution and kind of a hack. I have already implemented a hack to get around this problem. I was just wondering if there is a solution that is builtin that I maybe missing.

Comment: @MamoonAhmed What do you mean by "external solution"? jsonpickle supports `__setstate__()`: https://jsonpickle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#customizing-json-output

Comment: @aaron I have found one particular issue. existing pickled jsons wont work. By existing, I mean, JSONs that were produced before implementing a __setstate__ and __getstate__

Answer (score 1):

Implement the [`__setstate__()`](https://jsonpickle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#customizing-json-output) method:

```py
class LineItem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2

    def __setstate__(self, state: dict):
        state.setdefault('var2', 2)
        self.__dict__.update(state)
```

> existing pickled JSONs won't work. By existing, I mean, JSONs that were produced before implementing a `__setstate__` and `__getstate__`

You can override `Unpickler` `_restore_object_instance_variables` to always call `__setstate__`:

```py
import jsonpickle
from jsonpickle import tags


class Unpickler(jsonpickle.Unpickler):

    def _restore_object_instance_variables(self, obj, instance):
        if hasattr(instance, '__setstate__'):
            obj.setdefault(tags.STATE, {})
        return super()._restore_object_instance_variables(obj, instance)
```

Usage:

```py
s = '{"py/object": "__main__.LineItem", "var1": 1}'
context = Unpickler()
print(jsonpickle.decode(s, context=context).var2)
```

Comment: hmmm. Interesting. Let me try that